# Adding a new WCF service to an existing project

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm adding a new WCF service to a project, but the new one doesn't act the same as the old one.

Each has a similar SVC file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Company.Project.Service1"  %>
```

Each has an Interface that defines the ServiceContract and OperationContracts:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Service1))]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "json/method1", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    ResponseObject Method1(RequestObject req);
}
```

Each is defined in the web.config file:

```
  <service name="Company.Project.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Company.Project.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Company.Project.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

However, when I visit the URL for the original service in one of my pre-production environments using Chrome, I see the "Method Not Allowed" error I expect (since I'm using GET).

When I visit the new service, I get a 404 error:

```
Server Error in [Snipped]

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /[Snipped]/Service2.svc/rest/json/method2
```

The other oddity is that it worked in my previous pre-production environments, so it could just be something in the deployment process.

Comment: Match your configuration of pre-production with the current one. I'm sure you'd be missing something. Also you can try `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />` though it's not recommended if your API targeting non .Net client.

Comment: @vendettamit - everything I can think of already matches (the SVC file, the interface, the `<services>` section of the web.config). Do you have any suggestions for other files / config sections I need to look at?

Comment: Other reason of this problem could be; if routing is not defined in Global.asax. Can you confirm the code in app_start of global handler from pre-production and in the new env are matching?

Comment: I'm sure it would. But if you're adding a new service then a new route required to be defined for that service in Global.asax. e.g. If you add a new service i.e. ApiService2 than route has to be added for ApiService2 otherwise the resource won't get located from Asp.net pipeline. So you would require to add an entry like `routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api2", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ApiService2)));`

Comment: @vendettamit - I think this is it. The pre-production environment in question has an explicit call-out to the old service, but not the new one. It didn't show up in my code sweep due to the fact that it was in a different solution. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: If it answered your question I can write it as answer that would help others seeking same kinda issues to directly jump to the answer instead of reading all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have routing defined in your Global.asax file for the new service that you have added in existing project. This could be easily missed and resulting in unable to locate resource via Asp.net pipline in hosting environment.

So, if you have new version of service ,let say ApiService2, you would require to add an entry like:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api2", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ApiService2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I observed that your  method is called Method1 but you are trying to get to the  method2

Does your web config also have a section for endpointBehavior like the following. You need this to enable REST endpoints for your webHttpBinding . You should probably add a service behavior as well

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I'm trying to call Method2 in Service2. Apologies if that's unclear - I was attempting to de-identify the services.

Comment: There are existing `<endpointBehavior><behavior name="web">` and `<serviceBehaviors><behavior name="ServiceBehavior">` configurations in the web.config. I didn't modify them when introducing Service2.